# Rails log does not return a reason for a 422 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have deployed a Rails API only application, however the logs are very uninformative, it returns no reason for a 422 as you can see below. It is a delibaretily incorrect request.

[image]

This is everything related to logging in my `config/production.rb`:

```
config.log_level = :info

config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

How would I enable useful messages about failed validations in my logs?

It works perfectly fine locally, it's only the production environment that fails to return useful log messages. I tried tinkering with config/production.rb, but with no success.

Comment: The premise here is bad. Rails doesn't automatically log validation errors, if its happening in dev its probally due to a gem that you have added into the mix.

Comment: Could be, it's probably not a gem though, because my Gemfile is a default one, i.e. nothing related to logging/errors. `# Show full error reports.config.consider_all_requests_local = true` might be a reason for informative messages. I tried setting that in prod env as well, but it still only logs a status code. I am thinking Heroku is possibly overriding the logging config to their default.

Comment: Could be - but AFAIK `config.consider_all_requests_local = true` really just effects what failure app is used by `rescue_from` when Rails encounters an uncought exception. When its true Rails renders the red pages with tons of info about the exception. This  should not have anything to do with how you're handling requests with invalid user input as thats not an exceptional event and shouldn't be treated as such.